# Por que usar o IEnumerable?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, view, controller

Tenho o seguinte código em uma Controller:

```
       var carro = new List<SelectListItem>
        {
            new SelectListItem {Text = "Pegeout", Value = "Pegeout"},
            new SelectListItem {Text = "Chevrolet", Value = "Chevrolet"},
            new SelectListItem {Text = "Renault", Value = "Renault"},
        };
        ViewBag.Carros = carro;
```

E o seguinte código em minha View:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Categoria, IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ViewBag.Carros, "-Selecione-")
```

Porém não consigo entender o porque usar um IEnumerable para passar minha SelectListItem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` é o tipo esperado pelo segundo parâmetro de todos os overloads do método de extensão `DropDownListFor`, porém a ViewBag é um objeto dinâmico - em tempo de compilação não tem como determinar de qual tipo será a propriedade `Carros`. Por isso é necessário fazer a conversão (cast):

```
(IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Dados
```

Dessa forma o interpretador sabe qual método ele deve chamar.

O fato do parâmetro ser do tipo `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` te permite utilizar de polimorfismo e passar vários tipos diferentes de coleção como `SelectListItem[]`, `List<SelectListItem>`, `Collection<SelectListItem>`, etc. Você poderia, ao invés de usar um List<>, usar um array:

```
SelectListItem[] items = new SelectListItem[]
{
      new SelectListItem {Text = "Pegeout", Value = "Pegeout"},
      new SelectListItem {Text = "Chevrolet", Value = "Chevrolet"},
      new SelectListItem {Text = "Renault", Value = "Renault"},
};
```

E na view, pode deixar como está (convertendo para `IEnumerable`) ou mudar para:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Categoria,  (SelectListItem[])ViewBag.Carros, "-Selecione-")
```

Resumindo: você não precisa usar o `IEnumerable`, precisa usar um tipo que implemente o `IEnumerable` e precisa fazer a conversão da propriedade da ViewBag para o tipo adequado.

Comment: Muito Obrigado Marcus, sua resposta sanou todas minhas dúvidas !